# use date(now) equivalent in mapserver

Tags: mapserver, date, mapfile, environment-variable

I want to use present year in a CLASS in a map file. I managed to write permanent expressions like:

```
LAYER
    CLASSITEM "YEAR"
...
    CLASS
        NAME "Previous years"
        EXPRESSION ('[YEAR]'<'2015')
```

But I  failed to construct a working expression, which includes a reference to present time.

There is an example of what I would like to write:

```
LAYER
CLASSITEM "YEAR"
...
    CLASS
        NAME "Present year" # Year n
        EXPRESSION ('[YEAR]'=='([date format=YYYY]'))
...
    CLASS
        NAME "Previous year" # Year n-1
        EXPRESSION ('[YEAR]'=='([date format=YYYY]'-'1'))
...
    CLASS
        NAME "Archived years" # Years <n-1
        EXPRESSION ('[YEAR]'<'([date format=YYYY]'-'1'))
```

I adapted [date format=YYYY] expression from a MapServer template [page](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html).It didn't work.... But unfortunately I did find [no simple examples](http://mapserver.org/output/template_output.html#template-output) of templates imported variables direct use in a map file, especially for [date] variables.

Has someone any idea of what it could look like?
I'm just looking for reusable examples that I could adapt for my scripts.

Comment: By reading the same page as you http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html I would rather try with `[data format="%Y"]`. I would also read some reference to strftime() for example http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what error do you get?  Are you saying that nothing matches your expression?  Does your attribute table contain a YEAR attribute? ```CLASSITEM [attribute] Item name in attribute table to use for class lookups.```

Answer (score 1):

I have an example that is working, (in the sense that mapserver does not make a timeout statement).

I have been investigating sources of documentation from [Template.General](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html#general), here I've found the syntax behind structuring the DATE-tag.

@user30184 posted [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strftime.htm) webpage, a manpage that explains the structure of the C-type syntax that "DATE"-tag is build upon.

Finally I've added a logical expression because the expression is supposed to work within two limitations of time:

```
("[*NAMEOFCOLUMN*]" gt "DATE format = %Y-%m-%d" && "[*NAMEOFCOLUMN*]" lt "DATE format = %Y-%m-%d")
```